# unable to bind Radio buttons with formcontrol with reactive forms in angular2

Tags: angular, radio-button, angular-reactive-forms

The idea is to dynamically add questions on the web component and here's what I've done:

function used for building FormGroup:

```
createForm(data) {
    this.survey = JSON.parse(data['_body']);
    // generate Form control
    this.surveyForm = new FormGroup({});
    for ( const question of this.survey.questions) {
        const fcName = 'q' + this.survey.questions.indexOf(question);
        const fc = new FormControl('');
        this.surveyForm.addControl(fcName, fc);
    }
    console.log(this.surveyForm.controls);
}
```

and this is my template file:

```
<div *ngIf="survey">
<form [formGroup]="surveyForm">
  <h1>{{survey.title}}</h1>
  <div *ngFor="let question of survey.questions; let i=index">
    <h3>{{question.content}}</h3>
    <div *ngFor="let option of question.options">
      <input
        [type]=question.optionType
        formControlName='q{{i}}'
        [value]="option"
        name="q{{i}}" />

      <label>{{option}}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
  <button type="reset">Reset</button>
</form>
</div>
```

this is the data in survey.questions:

```
    questions:[
     {
      "content":"What is Your Name??",
      "optionType":"Radio",
      "options":["Robin","Rainer","ABBY"]
     },
     {
      "content":"Do you Know me?",
      "optionType":"Checkbox",
      "options":["yes"]
     }]
```

This is my expectation if i select option ABBY and log this.surveyForm.getRawValue():

```
    {
     q0: 'ABBY',
     q1: ''
    }
```

and this is what I'm getting:

```
    {
     q0: '',
     q1: ''
    }
```

the console.log is giving me the data that I've initially set.

Am I doing something wrong here?
help is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I guess we can not use wildcards for input type:

```
<input
    [type]=question.optionType
    formControlName='q{{i}}'
    [value]="option"
    name="q{{i}}" 
/>
```

so i had had to define input tags for each option type:

```
<div  *ngIf="question.optionType === 'Radio'">
  <div *ngFor="let option of question.options">
    <input
        type='radio'
        [formControlName]='i'
        [value]="option"
        [name]="i"
        />
    <label>{{option}}</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="question.optionType === 'Checkbox'">
  <div *ngFor="let control of surveyForm.controls[''+i].controls; let j=index">
    <input
          type='checkbox'
          [formControl]='control'
          [value]="question.options[j]"

    />{{question.options[j]}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When making radio button inputs, ALL of the inputs should reference the same `formGroupName`.  That said if your formGroupName were `myRadioButton`, your template would look like:

```html
<input type="radio" formControlName="myRadioButton" [value]="valueOne">
<input type="radio" formControlName="myRadioButton" [value]="valueTwo">
```

Furthermore, this also means that your formGroup will only need *one* form control, the control for `myRadioButton`, which will have its value changed depending on which radio button the user selects.

Looking at your HTML, you create your formGroup twice:

First via the form builder

```
this.surveyForm = this.fb.group({});
```

Then immediately after again via directly instantiating a new FormGroup

```
this.surveyForm = new FormGroup({});
```

Either of these methods will work, but the way you have it, you're wasting whatever work you do via the first method once you overwrite the value with the second method.

Comment: this.surveyForm = this.fb.group({});-----> totally my mistake

Comment: but you see the data that i have in "data" is not only radio button options but also checkbox options and textarea, therefore 
        formControlName='q{{i}}'
i.e i have multiple questions and 'i' (index) is the index of a question and every question have its formcontrol ('q'+ i),
sorry for the confusion.
thanks

Comment: Please add what you're logging, and what the log result is.